# Join two lists in .NET while maintaining single property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two identical lists in .NET, this is how single item looks like:

```
public class InputRecord
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int OriginYear { get; set; }
    public int DevelopmentYear { get; set; }
    public decimal IncValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to join two lists of these records using LINQ while updating IncValue where all other properties matches. My code looks like that:

```
var output = template.Join(records,
    t => new { t.Product, t.OriginYear, t.DevelopmentYear },
    r => new { r.Product, r.OriginYear, r.DevelopmentYear },
    (t, r) => { t.IncValue = r.IncValue; return t; }).ToList();
```

Template contains about 50 records, while records contains 12 entries. I expect the output to have 50 records with IncValue updated where all other properties matched, however my output is only 12 records. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please supply a sample dataset that reproduces the issue?

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for updating. You can also use LINQ for creating new objects and new `List<T>`s. Use `foreach` to update objects in place, possibly based on a LINQ query to select which objects to update.

Comment: However, to answer your question, do you know what a [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) does? It returns all records where the values are equal, so it always returns no more than the shortest list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "`join`" which will only return matching items that have matching keys in both input sequences, can you try using the "`group join`" operation between two collections instead

```
var output = template
    .GroupJoin(
        records,
        t => new { t.Product, t.OriginYear, t.DevelopmentYear },
        r => new { r.Product, r.OriginYear, r.DevelopmentYear },
        (t, rs) => { 
            var record = rs.FirstOrDefault(); 
            if (record != null) { 
                t.IncValue = record.IncValue; 
            }
            return t; 
        })
    .ToList();
```

The GroupJoin method performs a left outer join by grouping the elements from the left list (template) with the matching elements from the right list (records).

I played around in .NET Fiddle using the following 2 collections

```
    // Define the template and records collections
    var template = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item() { Product = "A", OriginYear = 2018, DevelopmentYear = 1, IncValue = 100 },
        new Item() { Product = "A", OriginYear = 2018, DevelopmentYear = 2, IncValue = 200 },
        new Item() { Product = "B", OriginYear = 2019, DevelopmentYear = 1, IncValue = 300 },
        new Item() { Product = "B", OriginYear = 2019, DevelopmentYear = 2, IncValue = 400 }
    };
    var records = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item() { Product = "A", OriginYear = 2018, DevelopmentYear = 2, IncValue = 250 },
        new Item() { Product = "B", OriginYear = 2019, DevelopmentYear = 1, IncValue = 350 },
        new Item() { Product = "C", OriginYear = 2020, DevelopmentYear = 1, IncValue = 500 }
    };
```

The items in the output was

```
Product: A, OriginYear: 2018, DevelopmentYear: 1, IncValue: 100
Product: A, OriginYear: 2018, DevelopmentYear: 2, IncValue: 250
Product: B, OriginYear: 2019, DevelopmentYear: 1, IncValue: 350
Product: B, OriginYear: 2019, DevelopmentYear: 2, IncValue: 400
```

If this is not what you needed then I would probably suggest sharing some sample data.